# Von Neumann Architeture

Tags: computer-architecture, compilers

Recently I came across with a question about Von Newman architecture (which is usually used) and whether the following statement is true or not?

In Von Neumann architecture data are stored in disk and instructions are stored in state registers. Answer to this is false. Why?

Now my questions is: -> What are state registers are they same as normal registers AX, BX, SP, BP we used or something else. -> It is wrong because data is not stored in disk rather than memory and disk right? If not why it is false.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture

Comment: Please perform some basic proofreading before you post a question. E.g., state the question in the title. Thanks!